# How can I set the attributes of an object to the value of another object's attribute (another class) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, attributes, instance

In this project I have two classes:

```
class StockEntity:
    def __init__(self, ticker, exchange = 'NASDAQ'):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.exchange = exchange      

        # Get the history
        ticker = yf.Ticker(self.ticker)
        self.stock_hist = ticker.history(period = "max")


class Curve(StockEntity):
    def __init__(self, ticker, startdate, type_of_curve, hierarchy_order):
        self.ticker = StockEntity.ticker
        self.startdate = startdate
        self.type_of_curve = type_of_curve
        self.hierarchy_order = hierarchy_order
        self.stock_hist = StockEntity.stock_hist
```

The concept here is that each instance of StockEntity has a ticker symbol, and a history of stock trading data.

So I would say AAPL = StockEntity('AAPL'). That works fine. If I want to make a chart of the trading data, i can simply use the values in AAPL.stock_hist which gives me a dataframe to work with.

Now, for each stock, i also want to be able to do create curves based on calculations.

So i created the other class Curve, where i pass a StockEntity object as a property, the idea being, that, while I need the object of the class Curve for 'AAPL' to be an (instance of an) object by itself, it would make sense to make use of the same data that sits in the AAPL object.

However, when I do:

AAPL = StockEntity('AAPL')

and then do

AAPL_curve = Curve(AAPL, '2020-01-01', 'S', 1) i get an error saying "AttributeError: type object 'Stock_entity' has no attribute 'ticker'"

HUH?

If I type 'AAPL.ticker' it returns 'AAPL' as expected! So there is no doubt the attribute is there.

What am i missing here? Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: AAPL (the instance) has a ticker attribute, StockEntity (the class) does not. Also the mix of inheritance *and* composition seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Starting to think it makes mores sense to use nested classes instead......

Comment: I can't see nested classes being a better solution here. I think composition makes sense, a Curve *has a* StockEntity (and that's how you're currently creating it), your code just needs to reflect that.

Comment: Thank Jon. Yes, I agree. Did some more research and nested classes are not the solution. I am stuck though, as how to make the code reflect it properly.. Would you mind giving some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Curve():
    def __init__(self, stock, startdate, type_of_curve, hierarchy_order):
        self.ticker = stock.ticker
        self.startdate = startdate
        self.type_of_curve = type_of_curve
        self.hierarchy_order = hierarchy_order
        self.stock_hist = stock.stock_hist
```

Try just passing the stock entity as an attribute maybe?